# Sup preserving maps between distributive lattices

Tags: ct.category-theory, lattice-theory

I have been looking at categories of sup semilattices and sup preserving maps.  If $A$ and $B$ are two such, the set I denote $[A,B]$ is sup preserving homomorphisms between is also a sup semilattice with pointwise sup.  Even if $A$ and $B$ are lattices, $[A,B]$ might not be.  It is, however, if $B$ is complete or $A$ is finite.  The question I asking is when is it a distributive lattice, assuming both $A$ and $B$ are.  It is if $A$ is finite, but I can get no handle on it otherwise.  Does anyone know?

Comment: I do not know.  The example on page 723 of Grätzer and Schmidt, "On the Lattice of All Join-Endomorphisms of a Lattice," Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society 9 (1958), 722-726 shows that [A,A] need not be a lattice even if A is distributive.